# How to display WooCommerce Featured Products but in custom order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any way to display featured products in the way I want?
Assume there are 5 products A,B,C,D and E.
Now I want them to display like D, C, A, B, and E. Is this possible?

Comment: Sort by what ? You can go with ID and follow the order of the ids in the array. Here is an example - $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) , 'orderby' => 'post__in') ); Read more about query - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an option to do that already.
In each product ( inside Woocommerce ) click on the TAB "Advanced".
Inside this tab, you will find an option called menu order.

A greater number here simply means it will be further away from the beginning of the display list